# LeetCode: Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, array

Please review for performance

https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that
>   each element appear only once and return the new length.
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by
>   modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Given nums = [1,1,2],
>
> Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of
>   nums being 1 and 2 respectively.
>
> It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the returned length. Example
>   2:
>
> Given nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4],
>
> Your function should return length = 5, with the first five elements
>   of nums being modified to 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.
>
> It doesn't matter what values are set beyond the returned length.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array
    /// https://leetcode.com/explore/featured/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/727/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class RemoveDuplicatesfromSortedArray
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void RemoveDuplicates5()
        {
            int[] nums = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
            int[] excpected = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
            int res = RemoveDuplicates(nums);
            Assert.AreEqual(5,res);
            for (int i = 0; i < res; i++)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(excpected[i], nums[i]);
            }
        }

        public int RemoveDuplicates(int[] nums)
        {
            if (nums.Length <= 1)
            {
                return nums.Length;
            }

            int current = nums[0];   //1
            int newLength = 1;          //2
            for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++) // i = 5
            {
                if (nums[i] != current)
                {
                    nums[newLength] = nums[i];  //0,1,2
                    newLength++;
                    current = nums[i];
                }
                //else continue to next item
            }

            return newLength;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to review here. This algorithm looks to be as good as it gets. I don't know how much value there is in nitpicking, but here I go:

#### Review

- *The summary tag should be used to describe a type or a type member. Use remarks to add supplemental information* ([xmldoc summary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary)) -> put the challenge URL in a remarks tag, not in the summary.
- The challenge provides an input parameter `nums` but [C# naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) don't invite you to use abbreviations. You could/should change its name to `numbers`.
- Your unit test contains a variable with a typo `excpected`.
- Your method is declared public, meaning you should check arguments against null to avoid the nasty `NullReferenceException`.
- You've added alot of inline comments to show how the algorithm works. Considering the simplicity of the algorithm and the presence of unit tests, I feel these comments don't add much value to the code, if any at all `//else continue to next item` etc.